# Android Firebase phone authentication INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am really new to android firebase and I have implemented the necessary libraries for Firebase Auth. I try putting a valid number, but the log says its:

```
W/JEJE: onVerificationFailed
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed ]
at com.google.android.gms.internal.nf.zzK(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.og.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.oh.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String mVerificationId;
    private static PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    private static FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        final PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                Log.d("JEJE", "onVerificationCompleted:" + phoneAuthCredential);

                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                Log.w("JEJE", "onVerificationFailed", e);

                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    Log.d("JEJE", "INVALID REQUEST");
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    Log.d("JEJE", "Too many Request");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                Log.d("JEJE", "onCodeSent:" + s);

                mVerificationId = s;
                mResendToken = forceResendingToken;

            }
        };

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNum = editText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, phoneNum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                verifyPhone(phoneNum,mCallBacks);
            }

        });
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                }else {
                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void verifyPhone(String phoneNumber, PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks){
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                "+639952874699",        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallback
    }

}
```

please tell me whats wrong thanks..

Comment: Make sure Phone Auth is enabled on the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers) and that you have downloaded the latest `google-services.json` file.

Comment: Yes i do sir.. i walked through the guidelines

Comment: Still gets me same result

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding [SHA Certificate Fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) solves my problem. Well, Im fairly new to this but I managed to show output and I was able to received a sms verification.

For reference here are my codes:
https://github.com/coozgan/TestingPhoneAuth

Comment: It's stated out in "Before you begin" section in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks

Comment: I have configured everything, added google-services.json, created the debug.keystore, placed it into different folders and added SHA-1 fingerprint into the firebase console and still I am getting the same error. Can you provide some more infrmation how did you manage to pass this verification?

Comment: What kind of error you do have? Did you make sure u have add Firebase auth library?

Comment: I have com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1 and com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1 (everything installed and compiled from the docs). I am executing PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber and getting 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed ]'

Comment: @HydraOrc I have updated my answer feel free to look at my codes.

Comment: @HydraOrc Okay, I believe you might want to get a new project and add your app again. Add the sha1, Download the google-sevices.json, and try to see if error still comes.

Comment: @Coozgan, thank you very much. I have just figured out my problem. I was trying to place debug.keystore inside my code folder and it should be located under $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android or $HOME/.android. Now it works. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue as yours. Even though I uploaded both the SHA1 it would still give a "Phone login error" prompt.

You need to link the Firebase project with Google Play.

Head to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/you-project-name/settings/accountlinking and on the bottom right click "Link to Google Play"

Comment: This is an extremely useful suggestion when the app gets deployed to play store. The debug version in your phone can always work without this however.

Comment: Many Thanxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 3):

Well after a while I'll just summarize all I found out about the phone verification. There are a few things you need to do and should remember for it to work.

These are the list of things you need to do in order for it to work:

1. Create an app and connect it to yours with the google-services.json you got from firebase. Put it in the correct folder and make sure you added in the Gradle `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'`.
2. In your app on firebase, go to `Authentication` on the menu. Then go to `Sign-in Method` and make sure to enable the phone provider.
3. Add a Sha-1 to your app. When going to project settings inside your project, go to the bottom of your app section and youll see a place to put the Sha-1.
   In order to get the Sha-1 you need to run this command

> keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore

as mentioned in the firebase guide for it. Notice this command is on line so run it all together, and what it will do is it will look for your debug.keystore file on your user in a hidden folder called .android. The default alias for the keystore is `androiddebugkey` so dont change it and the default password for it is `android`, So when it asks you for a password just use "android".
Then youll see a list of returns and one of them is Sha-1. Put it in your project.

4. If still nothing works, this is not always needed but make sure that your app is linked to a google account. In your Project settings->Account Linking->Google Play.

Also notice, this is written of the 16th of august 2017, you cannot do the phone verification on an emulator, so use a real device.

Hope it helps.

Thanks saurabh Yadav for the missing slash ;) apperently I have to put 2 slashes here in order for it to show.

Comment: Thanks `Project Settings->Account Linking->Google Play.` It works for me.

Comment: It Should be  `keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`  like this you have forgot to add \ before `.android`

Comment: Project Settings -> Integrations -> Google Play worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have also same problem.

After read some content i found some other problem and after run my application.

Problem 1: [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) link says that,

**Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on an emulator.**

So can you test and run only on real device not any emulator.

If you can run on emulator then same error gives.

**You can refer my github [this](https://github.com/pithiyasagar/FirebasePhoneAuthentication) link for Firebase Phone Login Example**

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your firebase-tools lib to the latest version, then call firebase logout followed by firebase login.

Comment: Well my problem is regarding the Verification. I want it to send me a sms but it doesnt...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for signed build and put it in play store,the sha1 of play store should be same as the sha1 of Firebase fingerprint. And once it's done you need to link your app with the play store through firebase login.Replace the new google-services.json file in your android app from the new one generated in firebase account after the sha1 key change.