# INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed, Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-authentication

I have an android app which uses firebase authentication (Facebook,Twitter,Gmail,Phone,Email). The following steps I have followed

> 1. Enabled all the authentication's in firebase console
> 2. Added the app debug and release "SHA-1" & "SHA-256" values in firebase project settings
> 3. Downloaded the latest google-services.json
> 4. Built the app using release config

The app is working fine in the debug environment, but when it does made a beta release in the google play. I get the following error:

**For Phone Auth:**
"And Internal error has occured.[INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed"

**For Gmail Auth**
"Developer error in toast message"
"An Unknown error occurred" in snacker.

Please help me, I tried a lot. I don't know what i am missing here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Firebase phone authentication INVALID\_APP\_CREDENTIAL:App validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432204/android-firebase-phone-authentication-invalid-app-credentialapp-validation-fail)

Answer (score 0):

I see there are so many answers "INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL" title for firebase. But there is one important step.

1. Please make sure you have added the SHA (SHA1 , SHA256) Fingerprint in project settings.
2. Navigate to Project Settings > Account Linking > Google Play "Manage Linking".
3. Download the latest "google-services.json" and update in the app.
4. **Important: You need to Unlink the app from Google play and link it again.**

The 4th step is very important for all other solutions to work.
Thanks :)